# Loading data from csv file into oracle database

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to load data from a csv file into a table in the oracle database using external tables or plsql.
please considere that i connect remotly to the database using sql* plus.

I have read that to use external tables or load data with plsql i need to create a directory first and then grant read, write privileges to the user (the user that need access right to the directory).

1. My first step would de to connect to the database as user that has create  directory privilege and execute the following statement:

```
SQL> create or replace directory MYCSV as 'c:\mycsv\';
```

But what does the **c:** mean ? The c driver of my computer, which i have access to? Or the c driver of the server where the oracle database is running and which is not accessible for me?

My problem is that I do not have any information about the filesystem of the server where the oracle database is running. I do not know if it c:/, d:/ or e:/ etc.
Where do I have to create this directory? on my computer (client) or on the server where oracle is running.
Is mycsv is a physical directory?

2nd question: do I need to have sql Loader or oracle data pump on my computer to use external tables?

Comment: Use sqlldr, that's what it's for. Don't use sqlplus for inserting data, it does a really bad job and causes shared pool issues when it's used for loading, and you can't use external tables as your data is on your client machine. SQL*Loader is the tool to use, no question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But what does the *c:* mean ? The c driver of my computer, which i have access to? Or the c driver of the server where the oracle database is running and which is not accessible for me?

[From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-DIRECTORY.html) (emphasis added):

> A directory object specifies an alias for a directory **on the server file system** where external binary file LOBs (BFILEs) and external table data are located.

A directory object can't see your client C: drive (unless you jump through hoops to share it); apart from anything else - which is mostly security-related - different users could look at your external table from different PCs and client applications, and they all need to see the same data, which can't be personal to you.

> do I need to have sql Loader or oracle data pump on my computer to use external tables?

No. External tables can use the [ORACLE_LOADER](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/oracle-sql-loader.html) or [ORACLE_DATAPUMP](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/oracle_datapump-access-driver.html) access drivers, but those are not the same as the `sqlldr` or `impdp` tools.

But... given your restrictions it would probably make sense to use [SQL*Loader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/oracle-sql-loader.html), via the `sqlldr` executable, as that *will* look at files on your PC.

If you don't already have it available, for example from a full Oracle client installation, then you can use [instant client](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/winx64-64-downloads.html) with the basic and tools packages. If you already have instant client for SQL*Plus access then you just need to add the matching version of the tools package on top.